# Error with List.removeIf - Kth Largest Element in an Array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

I am trying to find the Kth largest element in an array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class Solution {
    public int findKthLargest(int[] nums, int k) {
        //List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(nums); 
        List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(nums).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        int max = nums[0];

        for(int x = 1; x<=k; x++){
            for(int y = 1; y<list.size(); y++){
                int temp;
                if (nums[y] > max) {
                    max = nums[y];
                    temp = max;
                }
            }
        list.removeIf(value -> value.equals(temp.valueOf()));
        }
    return max;
    }
}
```

I am hit with the error:

Line 20: error: cannot find symbol
list.removeIf(value -> value.equals(temp.valueOf()));
^
symbol:   variable temp
location: class Solution

And if I move int temp in between the two for loop statements, I get this error.

Line 21: error: int cannot be dereferenced
list.removeIf(value -> value.equals(temp.valueOf()));
^

Comment: `List.removeIf` is available since Java 8. What java version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the task is just **to find** the K-th largest element, nothing should be *removed* from the list/array.

Just sort the array and return the k-th value counting from the end:

```java
public static int findKthLargest(int[] nums, int k) {
    assert(k > 0 && k < nums.length); // make sure k is valid
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    return nums[nums.length - k];
}
```